# How to update state data that is dependant on another state async data

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vuex

In a Nuxt application I have a Vuex store that first gets some "properties" via fetch from an external URL. I would like to then use this data to update another
state element called "locations", each of these "properties" have a "location" but I'm not sure how to run this only after all of the properties have been fetched.

```
export const mutations = {
    updateProperties: (state, properties) => {
        state.properties = properties
    },
    updateLocations: (state) => {
        const locationsArr = [...new Set( state.properties.map( property => property.acf.location_tab_group.location_table.city ) )]
        state.locations = locationsArr;
    }
}

export const actions = {

    async getProperties({ state, commit }) {
        if (state.properties.length) return
        try {
            let properties = await fetch(
                `https://...`
            ).then((res) => res.json())

            properties = properties
                .filter((el) => el.status === 'publish')
                .map(({ id, slug, title, acf }) => ({
                    id,
                    slug,
                    title,
                    acf,
                }))
            commit('updateProperties', properties)
            
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    },

    getLocations({state, commit}) {
        if(state.properties.length) {
            const locationsArr = [...new Set( state.properties.map( property => property.acf.location_tab_group.location_table.city ) )]
            commit('updateLocations', locationsArr)
        }
    }
}
```

So basically, I'd like to know how to call the "updateLocations" mutation only after all of the properties have been fetched.

Answer (score 0):

In any action, [`dispatch`](https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#actions) is available on the context object.

If I understand you right, you want to make sure `getProperties` has been called at least once before calling `getLocations`?

Is this what you were thinking about?

```
    async getLocations({state, commit, dispatch}) {
        if(!state.properties.length) {
            await dispatch('getLocations');
        }
        const locationsArr = [...new Set( state.properties.map( property => property.acf.location_tab_group.location_table.city ) )]
        commit('updateLocations', locationsArr);
    }
```